# nginx ingress force-ssl-redirect not working when used with SSL offloading

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

The [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) state the following:

> When using SSL offloading outside of cluster (e.g. AWS ELB) it may be useful to enforce a redirect to HTTPS even when there is no TLS certificate available. This can be achieved by using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"` annotation in the particular resource.

But I can't get this to work. I can still reach my app via both HTTP and HTTPS. I'm expecting HTTP to be re-directed to HTTPS

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: nginx
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: nginx
              port:
                number: 80
```

But I'm getting:

```
curl -I -k http://app.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.0
Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2022 09:26:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1341
Connection: keep-alive
```